# Outsourcing try-catch-block from api-controllers into one single spot

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Every action in my controllers has the same try-catch-block:

```
  try {
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    return response.json({ message: error.message });
  }
```

I don't want to repeat it in every single controller action.

How can you get the try-catch-block into one single spot, so it does not repeat throughout the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a higher order function like that:

```js
const handleError = func => (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    func(request, response, next)
  } catch (error) {
    return response.json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

Then you use it in your routes with your controllers like that:

```js
app.get("/whatever", handleError(myController))
app.get("/anotherRoute", handleError(anotherController))
```

Your controllers will contain only what you have in your example as `...`